# OS X 10.10 Copy / Paste Source file count does not match destination file count

Tags: macos, copy-paste

I have folderA and want to make a copy of all the contents within into FolderB.  I select all the contents inside of FolderA then selected copy and went to FolderB and pasted it.  When it is done, there is a difference of ~500 files between the two folders when I check the folder sizes.

When I move the files, everything comes across.

I cannot figure out why there is such a big difference?  Does anybody know what might be happening?

Comment: So 500 files that you selected are missing from the pasted result? What about the difference in total file size? Can you identify which files are missing? Are they particular ones? I presume FolderB is empty to start with?

Comment: Yes, FolderB was empty when I started.  I cannot identify which files are missing because there are 20,000 folders/files with nested sub-folders under FolderA.  The total folder size of FolderA is larger than FolderB.  The only thing I can think of is a permission problem but I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible, that there are *hidden files* in the source folder?

You could use this shortcut in Finder to switch between showing/hiding hidden files.

> CMD + SHIFT + .

If you want to make sure to copy the whole content anyway, open Terminal.app and enter

> cp -pr /path/to/source /path/to/destination

After typing "cp -pr " in Terminal, you can drag&drop the folder names vom Finder window to Terminal window.

Comment: It looks like the command cp -pr /path/to/source /path/to/destination was able to resolve the problem with not bringing the whole folder over.